# Change columns when writing a fixed amount of data per column using openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I am writing a program that will process a bunch of data and fill a column in excel. I am using openpyxl, and strictly using write_only mode as well. Each column will have a fixed 75 cell size, and each cell in the row will have the same formula applied to it. However, I can only process the data one column at a time, I cannot process an entire row, then iterate through all of the rows.

How can I write to a column, then move onto the next column once I have filled the previous one?

Comment: You can do a lot with Python and openpyxl. To me it is not really clear where you got stuck.

Comment: Please consider to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) if possible, or at least post what you have tried so far (code)/what you're trying to do (be more specific). This way, it's more likely volunteers on SO can help you.

Answer (score 0):

This is a rather open ended question, but may I suggest using [Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/). Without some kind of example of what you are trying to achieve it's difficult to make a great recommendation, but I have used pandas in the past a ton for automating processing of excel files. Basically you would just load whatever data into a Pandas DataFrame, then do your transformations/calculations and whenever you are done write it back to either the same or a new excel file (or a number of other formats).

Answer (score 0):

Because the OOXML file format is row-oriented, you must write in rows in write-only mode, it is simply not possible otherwise.

What you might be able to do is to create some kind transitional object that will allow to fill it with columns and then use this to write to openpyxl. A Pandas DataFrame would probably be suitable for this and [openpyxl supports converting these into rows](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pandas.html).